# Regular Expressions AND

Tags: regex

I am really not good with regular expressions and I come here for some assistance :). I am trying to combine regular expressions with something like AND. For example if we have a text file with:

```
abc1-xyz

abc1-ertxyz

abc1xyz

postxyz

abc1
```

I would like to match everything that starts with `"abc1"` AND also contains the letters `"xyz"` somewhere.

I know that I can start with:

```
/^abc1/
```

but I am not sure how to combine so it can also match to contain `"xyz"`.

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: What is the programming language? Note that you can use something like `^abc1.*xyz`, or `(?s)^abc1.*xyz`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kN1kK0/1

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it with that answer :). This is for puppet. Which is using Ruby. That is why I forgot to mention it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us with which language you are coding, regex engines are not always the same.

There is another ambiguous point : Do you need your string to **CONTAIN** xyz or to **END WITH**?

Considering you are coding on Javascript..

If you want it to contain xyz, try :

```
/^abc1.*xyz/
```

If you want it to end with xyz, try :

```
/^abc1.*xyz$/
```

Comment: *and contains the letters "xyz"* - Perhaps, OP wants `[xyz]`? Also, there is no need in the second `.*` in your first pattern.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you.  /^abc1.*xyz/